# How to install add-ons in Zen Cart which is in xml format?

Tags: php, zen-cart

How to install add-ons in Zen Cart which is in xml format? I spent a lot of time and i have many xml modules but i  dont know how to install. Please help me out ?? I am confused.

Thanks,
Zain Reza

Comment: which add on are you taking about?

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean an XML sitemap?  What are the add-ons you need to install?

> Can you please tell me wither how to install module as xml in zen cart
>   or refer any modules which is in php with intall intrcution of
>   Friendly URL, Breadcrums and Sitemap

Zen Cart Add-ons are, in general, adding to or modifying the existing PHP files using the override feature within the Zen Cart structure.

As an example, the Sitemap Add-on - http://www.zen-cart.com/downloads.php?do=file&id=367 - is mainly .php files (that add to or override default Zen Cart functionality) and a .sql file (to make the necessary database changes).  **There are no XML files in this download.**

The support thread for this add-on is http://www.zen-cart.com/forum/showthread.php?p=725347.  There are also full install instructions in the readme file of the download.

What software program are you using to open the add-on files?  Why do you think they are in XML format?  Have you followed the install instructions?

Comment: want to install the friendly url, breadcrums, site map modules in zen cart and i downloaded these modules from google search ans get xml files of module. But how i install the module by the xml file ?

Comment: Can you please tell me wither how to install module as xml in zen cart or refer any modules which is in php with intall intrcution of Friendly URL, Breadcrums and Sitemap

Comment: @ZainRezaMerchant i use Ceon URI Mapping (SEO) http://www.zen-cart.com/downloads.php?do=file&id=889 i have no idea why you keep mentioning XML